# Unicode delimiter in vb6

Tags: unicode, split, vb6, character, delimiter

i wrote data arrays at the end of the exe with delimiter. After I compiled, the app it didn't work on Chinese Windows, only on English, i tried to use unicode characters for delimiter(example below) but the file seems damaged and cannot be runned at all.

`StringArray = Split(Mydata, ChrW(&H4E00))`

is there any alternatives?

Comment: Can you add more code showing how you store the data and also how you read it back? Its too hard to understand without those details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your data arrays in a Resource file and compile that into your EXE with the "VB6 Resource Editor" Add-in. Then you can load back your arrays with the "LoadResData" function.

Comment: I think I tried something like this, I compiled my project into an EXE, then that EXE I loaded into the other part of the project with "LoadResData", but the problem is how to remove the delimiter or replace it, because the method is similar with "LoadResData "